# Why the progressBar is getting to 100% near the end and jumping over the 90%?

Tags: c#

From about 90% i dont see the numbers running 91,92,93....The bar is just getting to the end and then its on 100%

This is the menu click event that beging the action:

```
private void beginConvertionToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                automatic_ = true;
                button4.Enabled = true;
                beginConvertionToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

Then the DoWork event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork_1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            if (automatic_ == true)
            {
                int y;
                string[] newDest_files;
                System.Drawing.Image NewImages;
                string sf;
                string[] images;
                sf = @"C:\Fraps\Screenshots\";
                images = Directory.GetFiles(sf, "*.bmp");
                for (int x = 0; x < images.Length; x++)
                {
                    int procents = ((x + 1) * 100) / images.Length;
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(procents, images[x]);
                    if (cancel_ == true)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        break;
                    }

                        NewImages = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(images[x]);
                        batch_Resize(NewImages);
                        if (NewImages != null)
                        NewImages.Dispose();
                }
            }
            e.Result = "All files converted successfully";
        }
```

batch_Resize function code:

```
private void batch_Resize(Image sourceImage)
        {
            Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(512, 512);
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                gr.DrawImage(sourceImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height));
                i = i + 1;
                newImage.Save(@"d:\NewImages\" + i.ToString("D6") + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }

            if (newImage != null)
                newImage.Dispose();
        }
```

And the progress Changed event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;


            listBox1.Items.Add( "Converting File: " + e.UserState.ToString());
            textBox1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
            label4.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";

        }
```

And the completed event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
            }
            else if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("Convertion Have been canceled");
                button4.Enabled = false;
            }
            if (cancel_ == true)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                button4.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

It seems like from 90% the bar progress is continue the green color but the then in the end its 100% and its not ocunting from 90 to 100.

Comment: Did you check the value ranges of i within batch_Resize? Maybe the D6 is not enough and causing it to fail the save (file already exists)?

Comment: Also check the values of procents, you might be missing resolution if the values are not always ints...

Comment: Do you really have a global variable named `i` ?

Comment: Is the max value of your progress bar 100? Also, if the value goes over the max of the progress bar it might be throwing an exception. I usually put a try catch in my progress event handler just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might happen too quick. Try to add a wait time (for testing purposes) so you can check if it is displayed correctly or not.

Not sure how to do that on C#, but on Java it would be a Thread.sleep()

Comment: I checked now and see that the percentages are end with 100 the one before is 97 then its jumping by two 97,95,93,91...then around 40 its jumping in two 40,38,36,34...where the first number the first percentage is 2. And it suppose ot count 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...